# After install and boot selection, the screen is inactive

Tags: system-installation, graphics

I just installed Ubuntu for Desktop 16.04 LTS with the ISO on a USB.

After the reboot, the partition/boot selection appeared, I select Ubuntu (the normal default launcher) and the screen is inactive (like when I disconnect the cable).

Computer:

- Intel E6600 2core 2.4GHz
- 16GB ram
- NVidia 480GTX
- Screen resolution: 1900x1200

Comment: Seem a problem with the graphic card driver. but I am not able to get back to the default driver. I tried also to install without proprietary software, but did not help.

Comment: You could try using nomodeset: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: I did, but nothing is different. I also tried no splash.

Comment: I am guessing one of my initial assumptions is wrong. You probably installed using a liveCD/USB where the drivers worked. This would indicate the problem lies elsewhere, possibly UEFI related or such. If you are able to access the GRUB menu you could try selecting advanced and recovery to see where the boot process halts.

Comment: It is not UEFI. Looking at the boot, it seem that it tries to load the "nvidia" drive, which is not found. Or something equivalent is written in the Log.
Yesterday, I downloaded/installed Debian and it seem to work, so probably I should delete this question?. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. No need to delete the question. Someone might stumble on it later and get a nudge in the right direction. It has happened to me many times before.